# How to create a rounded corner table using iText\iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have to create a table having rounded corners, something like it:

[image]

Can I do it with iTextSharp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is done using cell events.

See the Calendar example from my book ([Java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=96) / [C#](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/PdfCalendar.cs)).

Make sure that you don't add any "automated" borders to the cell, but draw the borders yourself in a cell event:

```
table.DefaultCell.Border  = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
table.DefaultCell.CellEvent = new RoundedBorder();
```

The `RoundedBorder` class would then look like this:

```
class RoundedBorder : IPdfPCellEvent {
  public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
    PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
    cb.RoundRectangle(
      rect.Left + 1.5f, 
      rect.Bottom + 1.5f, 
      rect.Width - 3,
      rect.Height - 3, 4
    );
    cb.Stroke();
  }
}
```

You can of course fine-tune the values 1.5, 3 and 4 to get different effects.

Comment: I understand your example but when I tryied to apply it into my example (I need it into a footer table) don't work and I still have classical corner, I have create a new question related to the specific case at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652856/why-i-cant-obtain-rounded-table-corners-in-this-itext-itextsharp-footer-table
If for you is not a problem can you help me? :-) TNX

Comment: I've answered that question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie If I would like to have a backgroundcolor for the cell, but contained only within the rounded border. How would you solve that?

Comment: I managed to solve it by setting cb.setColorFill() and then using cb.fill() instead of cb.stroke()