# Why I can't obtain rounded table corners in this iText\iTextSharp footer table?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have the following situation: I have to create a round corner table into the footer of my PDF using iTextSharp but I am finding some difficulties to do it.

First of all I have create a class named **PdfHeaderFooter** that extends the **PdfPageEventHelper** iTextSharp interface.

In this class I have implemented the **OnEndPage()** method that create the footer on the end of all pages, this is my code:

```
    // Write on end of each page
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        PdfPTable tabFot = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1F });
        tabFot.TotalWidth = 300F;

        tabFot.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        tabFot.DefaultCell.CellEvent = new RoundedBorder();

        PdfPCell cell;
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Footer"));
        tabFot.AddCell(cell);

        tabFot.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Bottom, writer.DirectContent);
    }
```

As you can see in this code I create a table named **TabFoot** that is 300px wisth and that contains a single column. I also setted the cell event handler for this table cells as a **RoundBorder** object.

And this is the code of my **RoundBorder** class:

```
class RoundedBorder : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas)
    {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        cb.RoundRectangle(
          rect.Left + 1.5f,
          rect.Bottom + 1.5f,
          rect.Width - 3,
          rect.Height - 3, 4
        );
        cb.Stroke();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my program work and the PDF is generated but the table in the footer have not the rounded corners but the classic square corners, I obtain this result:

[image]

Why? What am I missing? what can I do to solve?

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is very simple. You are defining the `NO_BORDER` value and the cell event for the `DefaultCell`. As documented, the properties of the default cell are used when you add a cell without creating a cell yourself. For instance:

```
table.AddCell("Test 1");
```

In your case, you are not using the default cell, you are creating your own `PdfPCell` instance:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Footer"));
```

This `cell` instance has its properties of its own. It doesn't look at what you defined for the `DefaultCell` (otherwise there would be no way to introduce properties that are different from the default). Hence you need:

```
cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
cell.CellEvent = new RoundedBorder();
```

Now the specific cell `cell` will only have a rounded border.

Comment: Is there any way to make border rounded of table instead of each cell, when creating own PdfPCell instance?

Comment: Yes, that is done using a table event instead of a cell event.