# How to introduce rounded cells with a background color?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have seen how to set rounded borders for a table cell in this question

[How to create a rounded corner table using iText\iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650957/how-to-create-a-roundet-corner-table-using-itext-itextsharp)

But is it possible to make cell that will have no borders, but colored and rounded background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, you need [cell events](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=201). I've provided different examples in my book. See for instance [calendar.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/calendar.pdf):

[image]

The Java code to create the white cells looks like this:

```
class CellBackground implements PdfPCellEvent {

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect,
            PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        cb.roundRectangle(
            rect.getLeft() + 1.5f, rect.getBottom() + 1.5f, rect.getWidth() - 3,
            rect.getHeight() - 3, 4);
        cb.setCMYKColorFill(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        cb.fill();
    }
}
```

For the C# version of this code, go to [Where do I find the C# examples?](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178) and click on the chapter that corresponds with the chapter of the Java version of the example.

For instance, [PdfCalendar.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/PdfCalendar.cs):

```
class CellBackground : IPdfPCellEvent {
  public void CellLayout(
    PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas
) {
    PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
    cb.RoundRectangle(
      rect.Left + 1.5f, 
      rect.Bottom + 1.5f, 
      rect.Width - 3,
      rect.Height - 3, 4
    );
    cb.SetCMYKColorFill(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    cb.Fill();
  }
}
```

You can use this event like this:

```
CellBackground cellBackground = new CellBackground();
cell.CellEvent = cellBackground;
```

Now the `CellLayout()` method will be executed the moment the cell is rendered to a page.

Comment: For itext7, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788267/how-to-apply-background-color-to-table-cell-with-round-corners-in-itext7